# Connecting clojure to Postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I am trying to connect my clojure program to postgresql db. I have the required dependencies. This is my `repository.clj` file

```
(ns webdev.repository
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as db] ))

(defn create-tables [db]
  (db/execute! db ["create table if not exists movies(id serial not null,
name varchar not null, primary key (id));"])

  (db/execute! db ["create table if not exists users(id varchar not null,
f_name varchar not null, l_name varchar not null, primary key(id));"])
  )
```

This is part of my `core.clj` file

```
(ns webdev.core
  (:require [webdev.repository :as repo])
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]
            [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET]]
            [compojure.route :refer [not-found]]
            [ring.handler.dump :refer [handle-dump]]
            ))

(def db "postgresql://localhost:5432/webdev")
(repo/create-tables db) ;;call to create the tables
...
...
```

When I run this, I get an error saying

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
```

Unable to find out what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**
Select statements seem to work. But insert and create table statements give the error "This result set is closed"

Comment: Top-Level code runs at compilation.  Don't put that there.  Look into proper means of db migration or if you want to kick-start, call that function in your `-main` and from the repl while developing.

Comment: @cfrick Tried calling it from main. Still the same error. All select statements seem to work. But insert and create table statements throw "This result set is closed"

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution using [conman](https://github.com/luminus-framework/conman) and [hugsql](https://www.hugsql.org/):

```clj
(ns ^{:doc "Database access functions, mostly from Luminus template."}
  your-project.db.core
  (:require
    [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
    [conman.core :as conman]
    [hugsql.core :as hugsql]
    [mount.core :refer [defstate]]
   [postgre-types.json :refer [add-json-type add-jsonb-type]]))

(defstate ^:dynamic *db*
           :start (conman/connect! {:jdbc-url-env (env :database-url)
                                    :jdbc-url "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/yourdb_dev?user=user&password=thisisnotsecure"
                                    :driver-class-name "org.postgresql.Driver"})
           :stop (conman/disconnect! *db*))

(conman/bind-connection *db* "sql/queries.auto.sql" "sql/queries.sql")
```

But even simpler, this is what you get for free using [Luminus](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/profiles.md). Just start your project

`lein new luminus my-project +postgres`

and it works out of the box.

Brief summary: don't reinvent wheels, unless you're learning to be a wheelbuilder. Stand upon the shoulders of giants.

Comment: Another option instead of Luminus is [Duct framework](https://github.com/duct-framework/docs/blob/master/GUIDE.rst)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using H2:   https://github.com/cloojure/demo-jdbc

You can clone the repo and run via `lein test`.  As cfrick says, the call to create the DB should not be at the top-level, which runs during the compilation phase.  Instead, the call to `create-table` should be inside a function that is called from `-main` (or in the example as part of a unit test).

```
(ns tst.demo.jdbc
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
    [hikari-cp.core :as pool]
  ))

(def raw-db-spec
  {:classname   "org.h2.Driver"
   :subprotocol "h2:mem"    ; the prefix `jdbc:` is added automatically
   :subname     "demo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ; `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` very important!!!
                     ; http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases
                     ; http://makble.com/using-h2-in-memory-database-in-clojure
   :user        "sa"        ; "system admin"
   :password    ""          ; empty string by default
   })

(dotest
  ; creates & drops a connection (& transaction) for each command
  (jdbc/db-do-commands raw-db-spec ["drop table if exists langs"
                                    "drop table if exists releases"])

  ; Creates and uses a connection for all commands
  (jdbc/with-db-connection
    [conn raw-db-spec]
    (jdbc/db-do-commands
      conn
      [(jdbc/create-table-ddl :langs
                              [[:id :serial]
                               [:lang "varchar not null"]])
       (jdbc/create-table-ddl :releases
                              [[:id :serial]
                               [:desc "varchar not null"]
                               [:langId "numeric"]])]))

  ; create & use a connection for multiple commands
  (jdbc/with-db-connection
    [conn raw-db-spec]
    (jdbc/insert-multi! raw-db-spec :langs ; => ({:id 1} {:id 2})
                        [{:lang "Clojure"}
                         {:lang "Java"}])

    (let [result (jdbc/query raw-db-spec ["select * from langs"])]
      (is= result [{:id 1, :lang "Clojure"}
                   {:id 2, :lang "Java"}])))

  ; Wraps all commands in a single transaction
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction
    [tx raw-db-spec]
    (let [clj-id (grab :id (only (jdbc/query tx ["select id from langs where lang='Clojure'"])))]
      (jdbc/insert-multi! tx :releases
                          [{:desc "ancients" :langId clj-id}
                           {:desc "1.8" :langId clj-id}
                           {:desc "1.9" :langId clj-id}]))
    (let [java-id (grab :id (only (jdbc/query tx ["select id from langs where lang='Java'"])))]
      (jdbc/insert-multi! tx :releases
                          [{:desc "dusty" :langId java-id}
                           {:desc "8" :langId java-id}
                           {:desc "9" :langId java-id}
                           {:desc "10" :langId java-id}])))

  ; Creates and uses a connection for each command
  (let [
        ; note cannot wrap select list in parens or get "bulk" output
        result-0 (jdbc/query raw-db-spec ["select langs.lang, releases.desc
                                             from    langs join releases
                                             on     (langs.id = releases.langId)
                                             where  (lang = 'Clojure') "])
        result-1 (jdbc/query raw-db-spec ["select l.lang, r.desc
                                             from    langs as l
                                                       join releases as r
                                             on     (l.id = r.langId)
                                             where  (l.lang = 'Clojure') "])
        result-2 (jdbc/query raw-db-spec ["select langs.lang, releases.desc
                                              from    langs, releases
                                              where  ( (langs.id = releases.langId)
                                                and    (lang = 'Clojure') ) "])
        result-3 (jdbc/query raw-db-spec ["select l.lang, r.desc
                                            from    langs as l, releases as r
                                            where  ( (l.id = r.langId)
                                              and    (l.lang = 'Clojure') ) "])
        ]
    (nl)
    (spyx-pretty result-0)
    ;(sets= result-0 result-1 result-2 result-3  ; #todo use this
    ;       [{:lang "Clojure", :desc "1.8"}
    ;        {:lang "Clojure", :desc "1.9"}
    ;        {:lang "Clojure", :desc "ancients"}])
    (is (= (set [{:lang "Clojure", :desc "1.8"}
                 {:lang "Clojure", :desc "1.9"}
                 {:lang "Clojure", :desc "ancients"}])
           (set result-0)
           (set result-1)
           (set result-2)
           (set result-3))) ))
```